# Do researchers from some universities not attend top CS conferences anymore because of conflicting open access requirements?

Tags: publications, conference, open-access

From [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125715/how-can-a-phd-student-lobby-against-university-wide-publication-restrictions) and [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/125719/958), it seems like the open access policies of institutions like Harvard and University of California conflict with the requirements of the top conferences in computer science.

Can researchers from these institutions really not publish in top CS conferences anymore? How has the change been received, and how has this impacted their careers?

Comment: I don't immediately see the conflict. Can you summarise?

Comment: Here is an article about UC breaking up with Elsevier. It isn't about conferences, though. https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2019/02/university-california-boycotts-publishing-giant-elsevier-over-journal-costs-and-open

Comment: @Buffy So "boycott" in that title simply means "refused to renew a contract with", if I understand correctly?

Comment: There may be more to the story. That is just one aspect, perhaps. If you follow the "answer" link in your post, you will find the official position of UC on open access generally, not just with Elsevier. It is problematic for CS people, I think, as conferences are our main outlet. But there is no particular reason that conferences can't use open access publishing. That is up to the societies that sponsor most of them (ACM and IEEE, in particular).

Comment: In my CS field, NLP, the "top" conferences are all open access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The conferences acquiesce to the university policy.

The way it works is that, when the publication agreement is signed, an open access addendum is attached and next to their signature the author writes “my agreement is subject to the attached addendum”. At least that was my experience when coauthoring with Harvard faculty.